# SQLite ignoring calculation used in with a WHERE statement

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to use an SQLite query to calculate when an alarm should become active.  I store the start time and the detent (the timeout or delay before the alarm becomes active) in the same table as seconds.  Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE alarm_log (
 scope integer NOT NULL, --REFERENCES scopes_inst(inst)
 start integer NOT NULL, -- seconds
 end integer,
 severity text NOT NULL,
 value text NOT NULL,
 details text,
 raised_by integer,      -- the scope id that raised the alarm
 detent integer,         -- detent in seconds
 PRIMARY KEY (scope, start)
);
```

And here is the query that I am trying to use to pull the active alarms using some simple math:

```
SELECT *,
  (start + detent) AS activated, -- the time that the alarm becomes active
  STRFTIME("%s","now") AS now    -- the current time of the query
FROM alarm_log 
WHERE end IS NULL
AND now > activated;             -- ensure that the alarm is activated
```

I have created an alarm with a detent of 30 seconds.  The start time is 1378870712 so it should become active at 1378870742 (see the activated column).

This is an example of the above query returning rows 4 seconds before the activated time...

```
scope       start       end         severity    value                  details           raised_by   detent      activated   now       
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ---------------------  ----------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
4           1378870712              warning     out-of-range too-high  min 500 max 1500  0           30          1378870742  1378870738
```

Now the same query returns that row 2 seconds after the alarm was activated.

```
scope       start       end         severity    value                  details           raised_by   detent      activated   now       
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ---------------------  ----------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
4           1378870712              warning     out-of-range too-high  min 500 max 1500  0           30          1378870742  1378870744
```

I would expect reversing the > on the last line to a < it should show alarms that are not active... but this returns nothing, before or after a detent time passes...

Is this normal behaviour?  The query looks fine to me.  Thanks for reading :)

**EDIT:**

I should have mentioned that I also tried it with the calculations straight in the WHERE clause, but it does the same thing :(

```
SELECT *,
  (start + detent) AS activated, -- the time that the alarm becomes active
  STRFTIME("%s","now") AS now    -- the current time of the query
FROM alarm_log 
WHERE end IS NULL
AND STRFTIME("%s","now") > (start + detent);
```

**EDIT2:**

Here's some test data:

SQLite styles:

```
scope|start|end|severity|value|details|raised_by|detent
4|1378935271|1378935842|warning|out-of-range too-high|min 500 max 1500|0|600
4|1378935854|1378935876|warning|out-of-range too-high|min 500 max 1500|0|600
4|1378935884||warning|out-of-range too-high|min 500 max 1500|0|600
```

CSV styles

```
scope,start,end,severity,value,details,raised_by,detent
4,1378935271,1378935842,warning,out-of-range too-high,min 500 max 1500,0,600
4,1378935854,1378935876,warning,out-of-range too-high,min 500 max 1500,0,600
4,1378935884,,warning,out-of-range too-high,min 500 max 1500,0,600
```

Comment: Real question here is why it isn't results in statement error. In general, you can't use select-calculated values in 'where'. Usual workaround is using common table expressions, but sqlite doesn't support these.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too but got the same result, sorry I should've mentioned it... edited my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from (
  select *, (start + detent) as activated,
    strftime("%s","now") as now
  from alarm_log where end is null
) where cast(now as int) > activated;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck I'm afraid.  Does the same as the original queries.

Comment: I have updated query, check it out. If it still doesn't work, please provide example data.